# conocen algun sdk o un api para generar personajes en androidstudio

Tags: android-studio, api, sdk

Estoy hiendo una aplicación y dentro de los requerimientos esta el hacer un avatar de cuerpo completo personalizable y quisiera saber si saben de un SDK o un api el cual me pueda ayudar a hacer esto

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Esta pregunta será eliminada, pero mientras tanto igual te interesa esto: https://docs.zegocloud.com/article/14616

Comment: @track3r gracias fue de gran ayuda